# What is so special about $\ln$ when using TeX4ht in MathJax mode?

Tags: tex4ht

This question is specific only to [TeX4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tex4ht/info).

When using MathJax mode in tex4ht, it fails to render the section title which contains $\ln$, but it works for all other symbols I tried so far.

What is so special about $\ln$?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is a document

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \ln x  \,dx$}
test

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \sqrt x \,dx$}
test

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \sin x  \,dx$}

\end{document}
```

It must be compiled as follows to see the problem:

```
 make4ht -ulm default  foo.tex "htm,1,mathjax"
```

In the above, the split level is 1. Anything more than 0 is needed to show the problem.

Now the HTML looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not using `mathjax` mode with tex4ht also solves the problem.

Here is the raw HTML generated. Notice that `\qopname \relax o{ln}x` is generated by `tex4ht` before `mathjax` does anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" >
<head><title></title>
<meta  charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css" />
<meta name="src" content="foo.tex" />
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ 'fast-preview': {disabled: true}, TeX: { extensions: ["color.js","AMSmath.js"], equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }, extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], tex2jax: {  inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, processEnvironments: true } }); </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head><body
>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >This is a document
</p>
<div class="tableofcontents">
<span class="sectionToc" >1 <a
href="#x1-10001" id="QQ2-1-1">\(\int \arcsin (x) \qopname \relax o{ln}x \,dx\)</a></span>
<br />   <span class="sectionToc" >2 <a
href="#x1-20002" id="QQ2-1-2">\(\int \arcsin (x) \sqrt x \,dx\)</a></span>
<br />   <span class="sectionToc" >3 <a
href="#x1-30003" id="QQ2-1-3">\(\int \arcsin (x) \sin x \,dx\)</a></span>
</div>
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a
 id="x1-10001"></a>\(\int \arcsin (x) \ln x \,dx\)</h3>
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" >test
</p><!--l. 11--><p class="noindent" >
</p>
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">2   </span> <a
 id="x1-20002"></a>\(\int \arcsin (x) \sqrt x \,dx\)</h3>
<!--l. 12--><p class="noindent" >test
</p><!--l. 14--><p class="noindent" >
</p>
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">3   </span> <a
 id="x1-30003"></a>\(\int \arcsin (x) \sin x \,dx\)</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug in TeX4ht? I will also report this to texh4t bug tracking now and add a link to this post (it easier to explain this here as one can add screen shots).

I am using [TeX Live 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live#Release_history) on Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`amsmath` defines math operators in a non-robust way, so they are partially expanded before written into an auxiliary file, e.g. while writing the table of contents. To fix this, tex4ht loads a file `.../texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht` which adjust these definitions. The most interesting part for us is:

```
\fixmathjaxtoc\int
\fixmathjaxtoc\,
\fixmathjaxtoc\sin
\fixmathjaxtoc\cos
\fixmathjaxtoc\tan
\fixmathjaxtoc\arcsin
\fixmathjaxtoc\arccos
\fixmathjaxtoc\arctan
\fixmathjaxtoc\csc
\fixmathjaxtoc\sec
\fixmathjaxtoc\cot
\fixmathjaxtoc\sinh
\fixmathjaxtoc\cosh
\fixmathjaxtoc\tanh
\fixmathjaxtoc\coth
\fixmathjaxtoc\log
```

(These are all the lines with `\fixmathjaxtoc`)

So you asked what is special about `\ln`? It is not in this list. What can you do about it? Add `\fixmathjaxtoc\ln` to your document. (It has to come after  `\begin{document}` because the definition of `\fixmathjaxtoc` is loaded pretty late. Also you want to make sure that yourdocument still works without tex4ht, so check first that the command really exists):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\ifx\fixmathjaxtoc\undefined\else
  \fixmathjaxtoc\ln
\fi
This is a document

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \ln x  \,dx$}
test

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \sqrt x \,dx$}
test

\section{$\int \arcsin(x) \sin x  \,dx$}

\end{document}
```

[image]